# Scalatra link image file outside application

Tags: scalatra

I can't seem to figure out how to display a file in a view that is located outside of the .war file. In the application I am working on I have a folder of images that is volatile at '/path/to/images/'. I am trying to link the file 'myfile.jpg' inside an img tag. In my view (scaml) I have the following code:

```
-val path = "/path/to/images/" + filename
%img(src = path)
```

This renders the following img tag

```
<img src="/path/to/images/myfile.jpg"/>
```

Scalatra resolves the src url to this invalid url

```
http://localhost/path/to/images/myfile.jpg
```

I'm kind of stuck. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I cannot store these images within /src/main/webapp/img

Many thanks,

AH